# How to add new column based on values of existing column in .txt file unix

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal

I have a .txt file like this containing six columns. I want to add a seventh column `V8` into the file based on the values of column `V7_Pheno`in a way that `Yes` should be coded as `2`, `No` as `1` and missing values as `-9`

```
V1       V2     V3      V4      V6     V7_Pheno
2253792 20482   NA      DNA     1       Yes
2253802 20491   NA      DNA     4       Yes
2253816 20503   NA      DNA     0       No
2253820 20508   NA      DNA     4       Yes
2253821 20509   NA      DNA     0       No
2253824 20511   NA      DNA     0       No
2253826 20513   NA      DNA     3       Yes
2253829 20516   NA      DNA     6       Yes
```

The outcome .txt file i am looking for should be like this

```
V1       V2     V3      V4      V6     V7_Pheno   V8
    2253792 20482   NA      DNA     1       Yes    2
    2253802 20491   NA      DNA     4       Yes    2
    2253816 20503   NA      DNA     0       No     1
    2253820 20508   NA      DNA     4       Yes    2
    2253821 20509   NA      DNA     0       No     1
    2253824 20511   NA      DNA     0       No     1
    2253826 20513   NA      DNA     3       Yes    2
    2253829 20516   NA      DNA     6       Yes    2
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for "awk".  Take a look at this tutorial (or another - you'll find many!), and see if you agree: https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html

Comment: Thanks But an example command line would be of great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==1{$7="V8";print;next}\
 $6 == "Yes" {$7="2"};\
 $6 == "No" {$7="1"}1' a.txt |column -t
```

1. The first line print the `V8` in the header
2. If the value of 6th col: `V7_Pheno` is `Yes`, then `$7 = "2"`
3. If the value of 6th col: `V7_Pheno` is `No`, then `$7 = "1"`
4. `column -t` : for better formatting

Answer (score 1):

With Perl:

```
perl -lane 'print join "\t", @F, $.==1 ? "V8" : $F[5]=~/No/ ? 1 : $F[5]=~/Yes/ ? 2 : -9' file.txt | column -t
```

`print join "\t", @F` print the fields of every line, using tab as the field separator.

`$.==1 ? "V8"` if this is the 1st line, print an additional field `V8`.

`$F[5]=~/No/ ? 1` else, if the 6th field is `No`, print an additional field `1`.

`$F[5]=~/Yes/ ? 2` else, if the 6th field is `Yes`, print an additional field `2`.

`-9` else, print `-9`.